# Illustrator. Change stroke thickness

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am in process of learning illustrator. When I want to change stroke thickness, I go Window> Appearance. Is there any shortcut for quick access? Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's no shortcut to change the stroke weight as far as I know, but for easier access you can change the workspace from the default "Essentials" to "Essentials Classic", or alternatively from the main menu, click *Window > Control*

[image]

This will enable the Control options along the top. So, now when you select an object with the Selection Tool <kbd>V</kbd>, draw a shape/line, or use the Pen Tool, you can adjust the stroke weight, fill and stroke colour in the Controls.

[image]

If instead you're just looking for a shortcut to open the Appearance panel, it's <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>. Or you can open the Stroke panel <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

You can also click in the Stroke Weight field in either the Appearance panel,  the Control options, or the Stroke panel, and hit the up/down arrow keys on your keyboard to increase/decrease the stroke weight. You can also type in the Stroke Weight if you need to specify an exact weight.

Comment: Many thanks. It worked well. Thanks. Thanks.